# Math equation result loses decimals when displayed

Tags: java, math

I am writing a program for class which will allow the user to calculate the area of an isosceles trapezoid. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class CSCD210Lab2
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      Scanner mathInput = new Scanner(System.in);

      //declare variables

      int topLength, bottomLength, height;


      //Get user input
      System.out.print("Please enter length of the top of isosceles trapezoid: ") ;
      topLength = mathInput.nextInt() ;
      mathInput.nextLine() ;

      System.out.print("Please enter length of the bottom of isosceles trapezoid: ") ;
      bottomLength = mathInput.nextInt() ;
      mathInput.nextLine() ;

      System.out.print("Please enter height of Isosceles trapezoid: ") ;
      height = mathInput.nextInt() ;
      mathInput.nextLine() ;

      double trapArea = ((topLength + bottomLength)/2*(height));

      System.out.println();
      System.out.printf("The area of the isosceles trapezoid is: "+trapArea);
   }
}
```

If I enter say, 2 for topLength, 7 for bottomLength, and 3 for height, I will get an answer of 12.0, when it should result in an answer of 13.5. Does anyone know why my code is printing out wrong answers and not printing the .5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base of the issue can be known as "Integer Division".  In Java, dividing 2 integers will yield a non-rounded integer.

Below are multiple ways to fix the issue you are having.  I prefer the first method as it allows you to use your formula with non-integer values.  Not all the lengths of a triangle are integers :)

---

Using the [Scanner#getDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()) and placing `topLength`, `bottomLength`, and `height` in `double`s will give you the desired output.

Your code will then look like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner mathInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    // declare variables

    double topLength, bottomLength, height;

    // Get user input
    System.out.print("Please enter length of the top of isosceles trapezoid: ");
    topLength = mathInput.nextDouble();
    mathInput.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Please enter length of the bottom of isosceles trapezoid: ");
    bottomLength = mathInput.nextDouble();
    mathInput.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Please enter height of Isosceles trapezoid: ");
    height = mathInput.nextDouble();
    mathInput.nextLine();

    double trapArea = ((topLength + bottomLength) / 2 * (height));

    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("The area of the isosceles trapezoid is: " + trapArea);
}
```

---

You could also cast your `int`s to doubles and calculate your `trapArea` as so :

```java
double trapArea = (((double)topLength + (double)bottomLength) / 2 * ((double)height));
```

---

OR even simple, if you want, convert the `2` you are deviding to a double :

```java
double trapArea = ((topLength + bottomLength) / 2.0 * (height));
```

---

All of these options will yield :

> The area of the isosceles trapezoid is: 13.5

Comment: Such a simple fix, I almost feel stupid for even asking. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you look around on StackOverflow, there are quite a few people that are getting stuck with the issue of Integer Division.  Now you know!  Glad I could help!  (see update - even easier fixes - depending on what you want to do)