# Display number in Textview with thousand separator and decimal format

Tags: java, android, formatting, decimalformat

How can I format, according to Locale.getDefault() of device, a float greater than 999.

For decimal format currently I'm using this:

```
DecimalFormat decim = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
tv.setText(decim.format(someFloat));
```

And for thousand separator:

```
tv.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%,d", someInt));
```

How can I combine both if I want to display `3.678,66` (or `3,678.66` - depending of Locale.getDefault())?

Comment: This has an answer (not accepted) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128526/how-to-format-number-to-certain-number-of-decimal-places-plus-comma-separators?rq=1. Couldn't find that before posting my question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
DecimalFormat decim = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
tv.setText(decim.format(someFloat));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
NumberFormat.getInstance().format(my number)
```

to format to default locale

Comment: Will this limit display to two decimals places, as in the example I posted? I want to format to default locale, but as in the code shown - two decimal places max, only if necessary (ie. not `3.678,00`).